# Hive Custom SerDe returns all null columns if select * from table but returns values if select column from table

Tags: select, hive

I have a Hive SerDe i wrote. It works fine when selecting columns in the hive query like:

select columnName from table;

But, when I do:

select * from table;

It is returning all nulls. I am returning a list object with all column values in the deserialize override method.